# Headphone mic doesn't work on clevo p650se

Tags: headphones, microphone, audio-jack

I've always had a problem with headphones since 14.04. I'm using 16.04 LTS right now. I've managed to make my headphones work with hdajackretask with the help of this [thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2293003), though neither the built-in microphone on my computer nor the microphone of my headphone doesn't work. I have dual-boot windows 10 and everything works fine in windows 10.

Comment: Is the connector a combo-jack (microphone and headphone), or are they 2 separate connectors?

Comment: It is a combo-jack. The headphone is a regular samsung headphone that comes out of the box beside the phone.

Comment: Could you paste the output of this please: `lspci | grep -i Audio`, also, how many rings do your headphones have?

Comment: Then that is to be expected. That you can reassign inputs and outputs in Windows or Ubuntu doesn't mean you should. Just use a Y adapter like all the smart people do.

Comment: 00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
and 3 rings

Comment: Do the 2 mics both show on sound input settings, and do they both move when you speak?

Comment: That's it. I don't know why but sound input was muted in the input settings. I wouldn't be able find it without your help thanks.